# Subgroup, H, containing a p-Sylow subgroup of the group G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we are given a group $G$ of order $60$, which contains a normal proper non-trivial subgroup $H$.
Why is it true that if $ 5 | |H| $ then $H$ contains a $5$-Sylow subgroup of $G$?

I am having a hard time proving this to myself.

Comment: The condition of normality is superfluous here.

Answer (score 1):

Since $60 = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$, any $5$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ has order exactly $5$. If $H$ has order divisible by $5$, then it contains a subgroup with $5$ elements generated by an element of order $5$ (as a consequence of Cauchy's theorem, or by a Sylow theorem); this is, in turn, a subgroup of $G$ of order $5$ generated by that same element. But a subgroup of order $5$ is exactly a $5$-Sylow subgroup of $G$.